# How to remove outlier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers

I'm working on n a regression problem. I have 10 independent variables.I'm using SVR. Despite doing feature selection and tuning SVR parameters Using Grid search, I got huge MAPE which is 15%. So I'm trying to remove outliers but after removing them I cannot split the data. My question is do outliers affect the accuracy of regression?

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
features=pd.read_csv('selectedData.csv')
target = features['SYSLoad']
features= features.drop('SYSLoad', axis = 1)


from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
z = np.abs(stats.zscore(features))
print(z)
threshold = 3
print(np.where(z > 3))
features2 = features[(z < 3).all(axis=1)]


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_input, test_input, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(features2, target, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
```

while executing the following code I get this error.

> "samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
>
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [33352, 35064]"

Comment: Outliers can sometimes affect your model this because after normalization many values might become too small, I would suggest using Boxplots to identify upper and lower quartiles and then drop the remaining values that don't fall in that range, but only do this if you have enough data. If you need the code to do that, comment below and I will help you, but that will take some time.

Comment: @anand_v.singh Thank  you and Yes Code will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because, while your `target` variable is of equal length with `features` (presumably 35064) due to:

```
target = features['SYSLoad']
```

your `features2` variable is of lesser length (presumably 33352), i.e. it is a *subset* of `features`, due to:

```
features2 = features[(z < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

and your `train_test_split` justifiably complains that the lengths of your features & labels are not equal.

So, you should also subset your `target` accordingly, and use this `target2` in your `train_test_split`:

```
target2 = target[(z < 3).all(axis=1)]
train_input, test_input, train_target, test_target = train_test_split(features2, target2, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
```